# pandas to_csv function not writing to Blob Storage when called from Spark UDF

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am using a Spark UDF to read some data from a GET endpoint and write them as a CSV file to a Azure BLOB location.

My GET endpoint takes 2 query parameters,param1 and param2.
So initially, I have a dataframe paramDF that has two columns param1 and param2.

```
param1   param2
12        25
45        95

Schema:    paramDF:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
           param1:string
           param2:string
```

Now I write a UDF that accept the two parameters, register it, and then invoke this UDF for each row in the dataframe.
UDF is as below:

```
    def executeRestApi(param1,param2):
      dlist=[]
      try:
        print(DataUrl.format(token=TOKEN, q1=param1,q2=param2))
        response=requests.get(DataUrl.format(token=TOKEN, oid=param1,wid=param2))
        if(response.status_code==200):
          metrics=response.json()['data']['metrics']
          dic={}
          dic['metric1'] = metrics['metric1']
          dic['metric2'] = metrics['metric2']
          dlist.append(dic)
        
    pandas.DataFrame(dlist).to_csv("../../dbfs/mnt/raw/Important/MetricData/listofmetrics.csv",header=True,index=False,mode='x')
    return "Success"
          
   except Exception as e:
        return "Failure"
```

Register the UDF:

```
udf_executeRestApi = udf(executeRestApi, StringType())
```

Finally the call the UDF this way

```
paramDf.withColumn("result",udf_executeRestApi(col("param1"),col("param2"))
```

I dont see any errors while calling the UDF, in fact the UDF returns the value "Success" correctly.
Only thing is that the files are not written to Azure BLOB storage, no matter what I try.
UDFs' are primarily meant for custom functionality(and return a value).However ,in my case, I am trying to execute the GET API call and the write operation using the UDF(and that is my main intention here).

There is no issue with my pandas.DataFrame().tocsv(),as the same line, when tried separately,with a simple list is writing data to the BLOB correctly.

What could be going wrong here?

Note: Env is Spark on Databricks.
There isn't any problem with the indentation, even though it looks untidy here.

Comment: Spark evaulates the dataframes/RDDs lazily. This mean as long as you don't call an action on your dataframe, nothing happens. A solution would be to replace the udf with a call to [foreach](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreach.html)

Comment: @werner I would need to research on the lazy behavior ,but just a query -> Doesnt asking Spark to fetch an extra column(using a UDF) for my resultant dataframe  qualify as action?

Comment: no, adding a column with the help of an udf is a transformation. Have a look at [this link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) for a list of actions.

Comment: @werner,but can I pass parameters to my function within foreach ?I need to do that.

Comment: The function that you use as parameter for foreach has access to each row. You can check the example in the link in my first comment. In your case, you would have access to param1 and param2.

Comment: @werner,Even after doing this, all the operations except pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(path) works. However I dont face this issue when running on  a single node cluster. And no errors are thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `display` on the dataframe